# Static pole mount for heavy monitor with VESA 100x100

Tags: monitor-stand

I'm looking for a static (no adjustments) pole mount for heavy 30" and 32" screens. The pole is 35mm, vertical.

I would like to get the screen as close to the pole as possible. No adjustments are needed - actually they are a con as they take space and are not easy to get tight enough for a heavy monitor.

All the options I have found online have tilt and/or swivel.